# The requested document was not found in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Please check web.config code below

```xml
  <site name="website" language="en" rootPath="/sitecore/content"  
  startItem="/home" cacheHtml="false" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true"
  htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" 
  enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

and in my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   FirstSitecore
```

The requested document was not found Sitecore

Yes I have installed multi site manager package, after it throws an error. Before that it works fine. What was the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

When using the multisite manager, sites are managed from inside the Sitecore client (/system/sites/). You don't need to modify the web.config anymore.
Check the documentation [here](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Multiple_Sites_Manager.aspx)

Also make sure to Flush the sites config with the button in the Configure tab.